# /boot is full, can't do anything

Tags: boot

I have a big problem, /boot partition is said to be full on Ubuntu 14.04 ; i read all the other topics, tryed a bunch of things.. Even delete all the content of /boot.. When I do that, `df -H` still tell me that /boot is 84% full...

Any idea ?

Here pasted df - h and ls -la

```
Sys. de fichiers            Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev                          2,1G    4,1k  2,1G   1% /dev
tmpfs                         412M    1,3M  410M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   311G    195G  101G  66% /
none                          4,1k       0  4,1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                          5,3M       0  5,3M   0% /run/lock
none                          2,1G     87k  2,1G   1% /run/shm
none                          105M     33k  105M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                     247M    237M     0 100% /boot

total 31649
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     3072 nov.   2 20:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root     4096 nov.   2 19:10 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1271765 nov.   2 20:09 abi-3.19.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   177808 nov.   2 20:09 config-3.19.0-43-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 nov.   2 20:09 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 20614484 nov.   2 20:09 initrd.img-3.19.0-43-generic
drwx------  2 root root     1024 nov.   2 20:09 lost+found
-rw-------  1 root root  3628871 nov.   2 20:09 System.map-3.19.0-43-generic
drwx------  4 root root     1024 mars  13  2016 .Trash-0
-rw-------  1 root root  6571600 nov.   2 20:09 vmlinuz-3.19.0-43-generic
```

Comment: what's about `sudo ls -la /boot/.Trash-0`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to remove the `/boot/.Trash-0` directory for starters.

To see how much space is being used by `/boot` and the sub-directories, use: `du /boot -h`

```
752K    /boot/extlinux/themes/debian-wheezy
756K    /boot/extlinux/themes
832K    /boot/extlinux
2.5M    /boot/grub/i386-pc
20K     /boot/grub/locale
2.3M    /boot/grub/fonts
7.2M    /boot/grub
565M    /boot
```

The listing above is a plain vanilla `/boot` directory listing. You obviously have files / sub-directories in yours which should not be there under normal circumstances.

Compare this listing to your own and you should be able to quickly spot directories that do not belong. Note that my `/boot` main directory is very large because I have 12 kernels installed instead of the normal average of 2.